# NameError when trying to populate form field from model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm currently exploring django forms and have a issue I hope someone can help me with.

I'm following an example taken from [Creating forms from models | Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example)

I have the form;

```
# forms.py

from django import forms
from my_project.my_app.models import Author

class AuthorForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=3,
            widget=forms.Select(choices=TITLE_CHOICES))
    birth_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
```

and the model;

```
#models.py

from django.db import models

TITLE_CHOICES = (
    ('MR', 'Mr.'),
    ('MRS', 'Mrs.'),
    ('MS', 'Ms.'),
)
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

However, when I receive the following error when I try to access the form;

> NameError at /
>
> name 'TITLE_CHOICES' is not defined
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>     http://192.168.1.111:8000/ Django
>   Version:  1.2.4 Exception Type:
>     NameError Exception Value:  name
>   'TITLE_CHOICES' is not defined

Is there something I should be doing to allow forms.py to access TITLE_CHOICES in models.py?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to have completely ignored or misread the documentation you link to. This isn't a modelform - it's a standard form. You shouldn't need to re-declare the fields at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TITLE_CHOICES` should be defined inside of the class:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    TITLE_CHOICES = (
        ('MR', 'Mr.'),
        ('MRS', 'Mrs.'),
        ('MS', 'Ms.'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And in the form:

```
from django import forms
from my_project.my_app.models import Author

class AuthorForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=3,
            widget=forms.Select(choices=Author.TITLE_CHOICES))
    birth_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
```

Comment: Thanks dgel, your answer has fix the problem. Thanks very much.

Comment: No problem. You should consider Daniel's comment though and reread the documentation on model forms- a modelform will automagically get all the correct form fields from the model itself, you don't need to define them.